# How to capture snapshot of entire large ScrollView [Expo] [ReactNative]

Tags: react-native, expo

I want to take a screenshot of a entire (large on height) ScrollView.
I'm using Expo.takeSnapshotAsync to take the screenshot, but the returned image is truncated (croped) on height, hiding some part of ScrollView content.

This behavior could observed on both platforms, ios and android, using expo sdk v25.0.0.

Any tip is welcome.

Thanks!